# How to know if artisan is installed on my server to run a cron job?

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I am new in laravel, recently started working on a project that had already been started by another person, the version of laravel is 5.1 and we are using cPanel, the question is I want to implement a cron job and I do not know what Route to give for the  Laravel Scheduler to work,The structure of the project consists of two directories.

```
-public_html
   -loupper.com
      -loupper
      -loupper-jef
```

the first one called "loupper" is where laravel is installed, and is used only as the enroutador, there is a second folder called "loupper-jef", in which is the entire front end, The project works as follows, we send ajax requests with jquery to the directory "loupper", where this laravel, and this returns the information, how can I check if artisan is working and thus to know the cron job will work? As it is done on the server, any recommendations would be very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`artisan` is just a PHP script which lives in Laravel project directory. To make sure if it works, go to Laravel directory and enter `php artisan` command:

```
cd /home/laravel-project
php artisan
```

You should see a list of available Artisan commands.

Comment: Thanks for replying ,dude. Should I use some program to connect to the server and access their folders? I have never done tests on a remote server, how can I use artisan to view the commands from cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that you have already run `composer install` on your server's project directory.

In my case, I had forgotten to install all the composer dependencies so `php artisan` wasn't doing anything for me.